# Enforcing Authentication on App Close in Flutter Using Biometrics or Passcode

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am currently working on a Flutter mobile app and I am seeking guidance on implementing a security feature that enforces authentication based on the user's mobile device credentials, such as face ID, touch ID, or passcode. Specifically, I want to prompt the user to authenticate using their device's biometrics or enter a passcode every time the app is closed and reopened, ensuring that the entire app is secured.

While I have multiple scaffolds in the app, I am looking to wrap the entire application with a single class to streamline the authentication process.

I would appreciate any advice, code snippets, or recommended packages that can assist me in achieving this functionality in my Flutter app. Thank you for your assistance!

i have a class but i have to wrap each scaffold with it, but i cant navigate to a new page without closing the previous page as the authentication will be required twice